# Cron job execute every 45 days possible? (approx. 1 and a half months)

Tags: cron

After reading the crontab documentation, I can't think of a way of notating the following schedule: execute script exactly once every 45 days.

Does anyone know of am elegant solution? Thank you.

Comment: Set it to run daily. Have the script calculate the number of days (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946785/how-to-find-the-difference-in-days-between-two-dates) since the first day you want it to run. Divide by 45. Exit out if it's not 0.

Comment: Clever! I'll try and get this working.

Comment: 2 and a half month is not 45 days. It's 76 days, 2 hours, 12 minutes, and 45 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for changing the details. I made a mistake in my original post! It should have been 1 and a half months = approx 45 days.

Comment: @GustavMahler So do you want it exactly 8 times per year or exactly once every 45 days?

Comment: exactly every 45 days.

Comment: @GustavMahler In that case why do you say 1 and a half month? If it runs every 45 days it will run on average 8.1165 times per year.

Comment: For SEO so others with similar queries will find this as a helpful future resource. I've updated the question for clarity.

Comment: @GustavMahler The question is still ambiguous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74597/discussion-between-gustavmahler-and-kasperd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a period of 45 days does not divide nicely into the weeks, months, or years of the Gregorian calendar there is no way to restrict which dates your script runs on and still have it execute on all of the days which you want.

Because of that you will need to have your command run every single day and have the command itself return without doing anything on 44 out of every 45 days.

For example if you want the script to run at 03:17 the command could look like this:

```
17 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/your-script
```

And inside the script you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $[($(date +%s)/86400)%45] != 0 ]]
then
    return
fi

real things happen here
```

The `!= 0` part can use a different number depending on which day you want it to run the first time. And you can choose to put that extra logic in the crontab rather than in the script, though I personally find it more readable to do it in the script.

Notice that if your timezone uses DST you may need to tweak the above to avoid the schedule shifting by a day when the clock is adjusted. The exact details depend on which timezone and which time of day you choose to run your script.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use two entries of cronjob 1st one is for a month and 2nd for 45 days

for every month use below cron

```
0 0 1 * *  your_script
```

and 45 days this cron entry

```
10 13 * * *  test $(( `date +\%s`/24/60/60\%45 )) = 41 && your_script
```

I got a reference from below link for 45 days cron schedular

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699075/how-to-set-cron-job-for-every-45-days

Comment: I can't figure out what the 41 relates to. Could you help explain it?

Comment: @GustavMahler I've just explained it in the original answer. 41 clearly doesn't make much sense in this question, I think 42 is  the canonical version :)

Comment: In bash, I get `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\%45")` try without the backslash in bash and it works: `$(( `date +\%s`/24/60/60 %45))` - in an `sh` shell (like in cron) it works with and without backslash